# Join two tables in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

So I have two tables:

1. Client (columns: idClient, nomCli,...)
2. Exercice (columns: idExercice, annee, idClient..)

and like you see, I have one to many between Client and Exercice

I tried this query: `SELECT c.nomCli, e.annee FROM Exercice e INNER JOIN e.client c`

but I got this exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

Comment: And where's your `on` clause?

Comment: Post the code of the two relevant entities, and the complete exception stack trace.